# How to determine the event source in an ActionListener?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

Ok. I'm not sure about the title of my question and whether I used the right words.
As I am a self taught total amateur I'm finding it hard to ask my question as I don't know the correct terms for things so I will write something in code and then ask my question. I've written it without import statements, setting up layouts and scrollbars and some other things just to keep it simpler.

```
public class Foo{
    JTextArea text;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Foo foo = new Foo;
        foo.go();
    }

    public void go(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JButton button = new JButton("One");
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Two");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(600, 300);

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST, panel);
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(button2);

        text = new JTextArea(10, 20);
        panel.add(text);

        button.addActionListener(new ButtLis());
        button2.addActionListener(new ButtLis());
    }

    class ButtLis implements ActionListener{
        @override
         // this is where I have the problem

        text.append();
    }
```

}

What I want is an if statement to go into my inner class (ButtLis) which will determine which of the buttons are pressed and then append certain text to the JTextArea based on that. But I don't know what to call to find out which button was pressed.

Comment: `event.getSource()` in your `ActionPerformed(ActionEvent event)`.  You will need to cast it appropriately.

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple options. In the current case you have, where the `JButton` objects are locally scoped within the constructor, you would need to check for `actionCommmand` because the objects are not accessible from the `ActionListener` with their current scope. So you could do this

```
class ButtLis implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String command = e.getActionCommand();
        if ("One".equals(command)) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

If you wanted to compare object source, you would need to give your buttons a global scope

```
public class Foo {
    JButton button = new JButton("One");
    JButton button2 = new JButton("Two");

    class ButtLis implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == button) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

A third option is to register the buttons individually

```
public void go() {
    ...
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             // do something
         }
    });
}
```

---

See more at [How to use Common Button](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#abstractbutton) and [How to Write ActionListeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Comment: Thanks. This looks like what I'm looking for. And after I posted I thought "oh hang on maybe the buttons should have a global scope" but just left them inside the method, being lazy and figuring that someone would point it out.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for, although I would hardly recommend it:

```
class ButtLis implements ActionListener {
    private JTextArea text;

    public ButtLis(JTextArea text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource(); // Warning! This is not good coding practice, because you don't know that the source will be a button
        text.append(button.getText());
    }
}
```

Instead, I'd recommend:

```
JButton button1 = new JButton("One");
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        text.append("one");
    }
});
```

That uses an "anonymous inner class" to define the action listener. For Button2, you'd say a similar thing. The benefits here are that the action listener is right next to the button that it works on, and it prevents you from having a single ActionListener that has to check where each event came from (using `e.getSource()`).

Comment: Yeah that's what I originally was doing but I wanted to avoid individual methods for each button as there were going to be more than just 2 of them.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your ButtLis, add this

```
class ButtLis implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       e.getSource();
       //Your implementation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the class that implements ActionListener:

```java
class ButtLis implements ActionListener {

    JTextArea text;

    public ButtLis(JTextArea text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (ae.getSource() instanceof JButton) {
            JButton button = (JButton) ae.getSource();
            if(text != null){
                text.append(" " + button.getText());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here how to add an action listener to the buttons:

```java
   button.addActionListener(new ButtLis(text));
   button2.addActionListener(new ButtLis(text));
```

For a generale ActionListsner, i suggest a different customer ActionListener like this:

```java
abstract class ButtLis implements ActionListener {

    protected String sourceEvent;  //or you can use a reference for the source object

    public ButtLis(String sourceEvent) {
        this.sourceEvent = sourceEvent;
    }

    public String getSourceEvent() {
        return sourceEvent;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        customer_actionPerformed(ae);
    }

    public abstract void customer_actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae);
}
```

And the adding of action listener for any component is the same as an ordinary ActionListener:

```java
//for exemple button
button.addActionListener(new ButtLis(button.getText()) {
    @Override
    public void customer_actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {        
        text.append(getSourceEvent());
    }
});
```