# Accessing child elements within a JFrame or JPanel

Tags: java

I am currently writing a small program.  Within the program, I have a JPanel that contains 400 text boxes set out in a 20 x 20 grid.
Part of he program works on assigning a color to a variable.  When the user then clicks on one of the textboxes, the background color is changed.
This is written within Netbeans and all visual items are set out using the Design manger (plus altering the layout manager to suit).

I have no issue with the design, the allocating of a color to a variable or even writing individual code that uses a mouse click event handler to set the background color to the color variable.

The reason for the question is at present, I need to write code for all 400 text boxes to make this work.  Is there a way knowing which textbox is clicked and assigning the color, without writing code for all 400 textboxes, maybe via the parent (JPanel)?

Comment: Simple -- use an array or collection, such as ArrayList, and for loops just as you would for any other large collection of similar items.

Comment: For this problem, though you want to use a FocusListener

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine the event source in an ActionListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22162257/how-to-determine-the-event-source-in-an-actionlistener)

Comment: @PM77-1 It looks like you could be right, but when I searched for previous questions, I was not aware of the right angle to come from.  Ill check out the answers given, see what helps and can then confirm if it is the same problem.

Comment: @Phenoxyethanol: the proposed duplicate offers insight into the use of calling `.getSource()` on EventObjects (such as ActionEvents in ActionListeners, FocusEvent objects in FocusListeners, and MouseEvent objects in MouseListeners), and so it definitely has a strong relevance to your question and your problem -- which in a nutshell is to try to identify *which* component has triggered a listened-to event to occur.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Simple: use a FocusListener, one added to each JTextField. For example if you have JTextFields like so:

```
private JTextField[][] fields = new JTextField[ROW_COUNT][ROW_COUNT];
```

And say you have a FocusListener like so:

```
private class MyFocus implements FocusListener {
    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        // get JTextField that lost focus
        JTextField textField = (JTextField) e.getSource();

        // set color back to white
        textField.setBackground(INACTIVE_COLOR);
    }

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        // get JTextField that is gaining focus
        JTextField textField = (JTextField) e.getSource();

        // set color to the active background
        textField.setBackground(ACTIVE_COLOR);
    }
}
```

You can create and add your listener

```
    FocusListener focusListener = new MyFocus();        
    setLayout(new GridLayout(ROW_COUNT, ROW_COUNT, 1, 1));
    for (int row = 0; row < fields.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < fields[row].length; col++) {
            JTextField field = new JTextField(COLS);
            field.addFocusListener(focusListener);
            add(field);
        }
    }
```

The whole testable thing:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FocusExample extends JPanel {
    private static final int ROW_COUNT = 20;
    private static final int COLS = 5;
    protected static final Color ACTIVE_COLOR = Color.PINK;
    protected static final Color INACTIVE_COLOR = Color.WHITE;
    private JTextField[][] fields = new JTextField[ROW_COUNT][ROW_COUNT];

    public FocusExample() {
        FocusListener focusListener = new MyFocus();        
        setLayout(new GridLayout(ROW_COUNT, ROW_COUNT, 1, 1));
        for (int row = 0; row < fields.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < fields[row].length; col++) {
                JTextField field = new JTextField(COLS);
                field.addFocusListener(focusListener);
                add(field);
            }
        }
    }

    private class MyFocus implements FocusListener {
        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            // get JTextField that lost focus
            JTextField textField = (JTextField) e.getSource();

            // set color back to white
            textField.setBackground(INACTIVE_COLOR);
        }

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            // get JTextField that is gaining focus
            JTextField textField = (JTextField) e.getSource();

            // set color to the active background
            textField.setBackground(ACTIVE_COLOR);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        FocusExample mainPanel = new FocusExample();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FocusExample");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer.  Ill take a look and see if it solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the panel. Just do this:

Declare this mouse adapter:

```
MouseAdapter ma = new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                JTextField tf = (JTextField) e.getSource();
                tf.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            }
        };
```

Do this inside the loop where you create the text fields:

```
textField.addMouseListener(ma);
```

The MouseEvent knows which JTextField was clicked, so you access it and change its color. Add this mouse listener to every text field and this should work.

Comment: This won't work -- 1. the background will *stay* black after changed, and will never change back to white. 2.  This will fail if the user tabs into the JTextField.  Much better to use a FocusListener since it is focus events that you really care about.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I agree that the focus listener is better, however, this is just a way to show how to change know which object created the event, so I know that it will stay black forever, it was not meant to be a final solution.

Comment: Thank you, I will look at this and see if it does what I need it to.